# Explicit expression $\int_{M} Tr(R \wedge R )$ in terms of Riemann tensor with coordinate indices

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, tensors

There is a quantity that we can integrate over a 4-manifold
$$
\frac{1}{8 \pi^2}\int_{M} Tr(R  \wedge R )
$$
such that the $R$ is a Riemann curvature two form or tensor. The trace $Tr$ is over the Lie algebra of the tangent space of manifold $M$. Typically $so(4)$ or $so(3,1)$ in physics.

### Question:

1. **How do we write this expression $
   \frac{1}{8 \pi^2}\int_{M} Tr(R  \wedge R )$ expicitly in terms of the [Riemann tensor with 4 indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor)?**
   Namely by employing this:
   $$ R^{\rho}{}_{\sigma\mu\nu} =
     \partial_{\mu}\Gamma^{\rho}{}_{\nu\sigma} -
     \partial_{\nu}\Gamma^{\rho}{}_{\mu\sigma} +
     \Gamma^{\rho}{}_{\mu\lambda}\Gamma^{\lambda}{}_{\nu\sigma} -
     \Gamma^{\rho}{}_{\nu\lambda}\Gamma^{\lambda}{}_{\mu\sigma}$$

Is that
$$
\frac{1}{8 \pi^2}\int_{M} Tr(R  \wedge R )
=\frac{1}{8 \pi^2}\int_{M} \epsilon^{\mu\nu \mu'\nu'} R^{\rho}{}_{\sigma\mu\nu} R^{\rho'}{}_{\sigma'\mu'\nu'} d^4 x
=\frac{1}{8 \pi^2}\int_{M}  \epsilon^{\mu\nu \mu'\nu'} R^{\rho}{}_{\sigma\mu\nu} R^{\sigma}{}_{\rho\mu'\nu'} d^4 x?
$$ into the formula.

Is that the effect of the Lie algebra trace $Tr$  is the contraction of indices
$..{}^{\rho}{}_{\sigma\mu\nu} ..{}^{\sigma}{}_{\rho\mu'\nu'}$?

Here $\epsilon^{\mu\nu \mu'\nu'} d^4 x= d x^{\mu} dx^{\nu} dx^{\mu'} dx^{\nu'}$.

2. It is know that this quantity gives rise to the signature of four-manifold.
   **Does $\frac{1}{8 \pi^2}\int_{M} Tr(R  \wedge R )$ apply to other dimensions, other than four-manifold $M_4$? Yes or no? Why or why not?**

Comment: $n$-forms can only be integrated over $n$-manifolds.

Comment: but I meant how to write this $R \wedge R$ explicitly in terms of all four and four indices?

Comment: Using standard unordered index notation, it would generally be$$\operatorname{Tr}(R\wedge R)_{abcd}=CT_{[abcd]}\\T_{abcd}=R^e{}_{fab}R^f{}_{ecd}$$where $C\in\mathbb{R}$ is a combinatorial factor which depends on the convention used in your definition of the wedge product of alternating forms. Note that the trace here is not a peoperty of the Lie algebras, but rather of their representation as elements of $\operatorname{End}(TM)$.

Comment: thanks can you show explicitly and write an answer? also - Do  ∫(∧) or ∫(∧$\star$) apply to other dimensions?